# HttpPost not displaying JSON response

Tags: android, url, post, httprequest

I am trying to display the response when I make a POST request. But nothing happens unfortunately. To make things worse, when I use the debugger, it freezes at this line `HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);` so I can't see if my POST request actually worked.

The response from the URL comes in as a JSON so perhaps I didn't set it up properly. I'm very new to JSON and Http requests...

Can someone tell me if something needs to be change with this method?

```
private void makePostRequest() {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://blablabla.com");

    //Post Data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", login.getText().toString()));
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password.getText().toString()));
    //Encoding POST data
    try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
       } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // log exception
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    //making POST request.
    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        // write response to log
        Log.d("Http Post Response:", response.toString());
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // Log exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
     // Log exception
     e.printStackTrace();
     }

    }
```

Comment: Is there a stack trace printed out that shows your post request failed?

Comment: No there is nothing showing it failed, but nothing is showing that it worked either...

Comment: What response code do you get when you add this line --> `int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();` after executing the http post request (after `HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);`)?

Comment: Response code never geta called. What do you think theissue is

Comment: Try putting `HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);` immediately after `httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));` in the same try-catch block and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: nope...and when i debug it freezes at HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost); The code after it never get called

Comment: Did you confirm that `login` and `password` are not empty?

Comment: update: i fixed the problem and got this far http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28508657/display-json-response-from-post-request?noredirect=1#comment45336440_28508657
but now i have a whole new issue... Thanks so much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Just Try this..it will work

```
public static JSONObject PutRequest(String url, JSONObject params,Boolean isPost)
{
    String result=null;
    try
    {

        String getUrl = url;
         jsonResponse=null;
         Log.i("Calling URL", getUrl);
        int i = 0;

        HttpClient httpclient= new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse httpresponse=null;
        if(isPost){
            HttpPost httppost= new HttpPost(getUrl);
            String json = "";
            json = params.toString();
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
            httppost.setEntity(se);
            httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");             
            httpresponse=httpclient.execute(httppost);
        }
        HttpEntity entity=httpresponse.getEntity();
        InputStream is=entity.getContent();
        result=ConvertStreamToString(is);           


        Log.i("Post Detail", params.toString());
        Log.i("Responsen String", result.toString());
        jsonResponse=new JSONObject(result.toString());
        Log.i("Jsonobject Before", jsonResponse.toString());
        JSONObject obj;
        try {
            obj = (JSONObject) jsonResponse.get("response");
            jsonResponse=obj;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("Jsonobject After", jsonResponse.toString());
        //return (new Gson()).toJson(jsonResponse,DataObject.class);*/

    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("Exception",e.getMessage());
    }
    return jsonResponse;
}   

public static String ConvertStreamToString(InputStream is){
    BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    String line=null;
    try{
        while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null) {
            sb.append(line+"\n");               
        }
    }catch (IOException e) {            
        Log.i("ERROR",e.getMessage());
    }finally{
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.i("ERROR",e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: It is not working unfortunately. Do I need to change the httppost.setHeader method? The two Json values the response should return are the user "id" and "description". So how do I get those results from login?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class WebWeb {

public static String send(String url) {
    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

    try {
        BufferedReader reader;
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream content = entity.getContent();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    Log.e("error", builder.toString());
    return builder.toString();
}
```

}

You will need INTERNET permission in manifist
Use this method in an Asynchronous Task's doInBackground method other wise it ll throw networkOnMainThreadException.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should organize your `HTTP` post request code, so it'll be easier to find the bug. Also, it is always a good practice to sanitize the user's input before making use of it. In your case, you should check if `username` and `password` are empty.

```
private String makePostRequest() {

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost httpPost;

    HttpResponse response = null;

    String responseString = "";

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    // check if the user's input is empty before using it
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", login.getText().toString()));
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password.getText().toString()));

    try {

        /* post request */
        httpPost = new HttpPost("http://blablabla.com");
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
        response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();   
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.e("ClientProtocolException", e.getMessage());
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Log.e("UnsupportedEncodingException", e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("IOException", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.