# Display JSON response from POST request

Tags: android, json, parsing, httpresponse

I have to send a POST request containing the parameters 'username' and 'password'.

I believe I did this below:

```
public static void execute() {
    Map<String, String> comment = new HashMap<String, String>();
    comment.put("username", login.getText().toString());
    comment.put("password", password.getText().toString());
    String json = new GsonBuilder().create().toJson(comment, Map.class);
    makeRequest("http://www.example.com", json);
}

public static HttpResponse makeRequest(String uri, String json) {
    try {
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);
        httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(json));
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        Log.d("Result", httpPost.toString());
        return new DefaultHttpClient().execute(httpPost);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

The next step says that I will receive a JSON response with an 'id' and a 'verification'. How do I display/parse this JSON response? I tried doing `            Log.d("Result", httpPost.toString()); but that clearly doesn't work and I have no idea what I am doing here.

Can someone please help?

Comment: What json String from server and where want to show both values ?

Comment: I'll show the values in the Log. What do you mean by json String from server? I don't have one. I just have the url

Comment: what string getting in `Log.d("Result", httpPost.toString());` line ?

Comment: org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams@41bf2b50

Answer (score 0):

Read response from server after calling `DefaultHttpClient().execute` :

```
HttpResponse  response=makeRequest("http://www.example.com", json);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
          new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (String line = null; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
    builder.append(line);
}

Log.d("Result","Response :: "+ builder.toString());
```

if server returning JSON response then convert `builder.toString()` to JSONObject and get all values from it using keys